# rospack cannot find package made by cmake even after sourcing

Tags: ros-kinetic, ros-package-path

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all.

I am trying to run some of rviz tutorials at [ros-visualization](https://github.com/ros-visualization/visualization_tutorials). In particular I am interested in "visualization_marker_tutorials". What I did, since I am more comfortable with cmake, was to:

```
cd visualization_marker_tutorials
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
make
```

It compiled without any issue and now I have a `devel` directory in my build folder:

```
$ tree devel
devel/
├── env.sh
├── lib
│   ├── pkgconfig
│   │   └── visualization_marker_tutorials.pc
│   └── visualization_marker_tutorials
│       ├── basic_shapes
│       └── points_and_lines
├── setup.bash
├── setup.sh
├── _setup_util.py
├── setup.zsh
└── share
    └── visualization_marker_tutorials
        └── cmake
            ├── visualization_marker_tutorialsConfig.cmake
            └── visualization_marker_tutorialsConfig-version.cmake
```

Here is the problem. I did `source devel/setup.bash` and it sets `$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH` to the root of build directory.
Now when I do `rosrun using_markers points_and_lines` I have the error of rospack complaining it cannot find these packages. What is my mistake here? Is it due to the fact that I am not using catking build system? If so, is there a way to build generic ros packages with cmake?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/251110/rospack-cannot-find-package-made-by-cmake-even-after-sourcing/) by [Pouya](https://answers.ros.org/users/3552/pouya/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2017-01-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Here is the problem. I did `source devel/setup.bash` and it sets `$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH` to the root of build directory.
> Now when I do `rosrun using_markers points_and_lines` I have the error of rospack complaining it cannot find these packages. [..]

This is only a partial answer, but the reason is most likely the fact that `rospack` will only consider directories 'packages' if there is a `package.xml` in them. In your `tree` output, I don't see a manifest anywhere.

I'm not sure why this is. You could try and see whether a `make install` from your `build` directory results in something different (make sure to set `DESTDIR` to something valid).

Perhaps @Dirk Thomas can chime in?

---

Edit: just checked again and `make install` does result in the package manifests being copied over to the installation directory. After `source`ing the `setup.bash` there, `rospack find $pkg` does resolve to the location in the installation directory, as expected.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-01-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Pouya](https://answers.ros.org/users/3552/pouya/) on 2017-01-02**:
`-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PRERFIX` and `make install` did the job. This is rather curios... But thank you very much for the help

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-01-02**:
I can try to speculate why `make install` is needed: a `devel` folder has no special meaning outside a Catkin workspace. Only because of Catkin can we do tricks by symlinking / overlaying `build`, `devel` and `src` folders, but `make` does not do that. `make install` is then needed to ..

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-01-02**:
.. create a flattened representation of the various directories involved, and only then does a `package.xml` make sense / is needed.

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2017-01-02**:
Copying files from the source space to the devel space is being avoided (the main difference to a "normal" install). So the package.xml file stays were it is. After sourcing the setup file the `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH` should contain the source folder of the package (whatever `build/..` is).